# Anomaly vs spontaneous symmetry breaking

Tags: symmetry-breaking, quantum-anomalies

I was trying to gain a basic understanding of anomalies. In the case of anomalies, certain correlations which should have been zero based on symmetry considerations of the action, instead turn out to be non-zero. In the case of SSB like in a ferromagnet-paramagnet transition, the expectation value of spins gain a non-zero value.

Phrased this way they both have the same consequences - certain correlations anomalously turn out to be non-zero. Is this correct ? 
Are there some deeper similarities/differences between them ?

In the first case this happens due to the variation of the integration measure under the transformation of interest, and in the second case it is due to ergodicity braking.

Answer (score 6):

A theory with a 't Hooft anomaly, broadly speaking, must have either have spontaneous symmetry breaking, a gapless spectrum, or give rise to a nontrivial TQFT.

There is an important difference between them: spontaneous symmetry breaking is a dynamical phenomenon--whether it happens or not depends on details of the Hamiltonian. On the other hand an anomaly is kinematical. It's there already at the level of the symmetry action on Hilbert space. The dynamical constraints above apply to any Hamiltonian which commutes with the symmetry.